# javascript - how to generate and save empty zip with FileSaver.js

Tags: zip, blob, 7zip, filesaver.js

I am trying to  to generate and save empty zip with FileSaver.js in Chrome browser.

```js
saveAs(new Blob([], {type:  "application/zip"}), "empty.zip");
```

it asks me to save "empty.zip" on disk.

file is being created fine (0 bytes)

i can drag and drop file in Windows explorer there.

but 7-zip does not open it

[image]

what should i pass as Blob content argument instead of empty array [] to get proper zip ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An empty zip file is not an empty file: it needs an "end of central directory record" listing 0 entry (see [4.3.16  End of central directory record](https://pkware.cachefly.net/webdocs/casestudies/APPNOTE.TXT) for the reference). Even with that, some tools complain that the zip file is empty. I can't test 7zip right now, it may happens to you.

If you don't want to load a zip library just to generate this empty zip file, you can write the 22 bytes:

```js
var buffer = new Uint8Array([ 80, 75, 5, 6, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 ]).buffer;
var blob = new Blob([buffer], {type:  "application/zip"});
```